# Sync in Cassandra data model

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm creating a social network app and i've denormalized data creating the timelines as a list of posts containing all fields in order to using only one query. The issue is that if every post has counters (likes, shares,comments), everytime a counter is updated how can I sync all post record in timeline? Or should i have only id in timeline and so i update only one table of posts and timeline query is made up of two query instead of one?

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about a similar task and here's my idea:

1. Timeline data *must be synced*. Storing only an id in a timeline and looking up in posts is a bad idea: you wouldn't want to make 20 lookups to generate a single timeline page. Also, it *won't scale*: once you add more nodes to your server architecture, different posts can be stored on different nodes and this will make queries slower.
2. It seems best is to use the `counter` data type for storing counters. This requires creating a separate counters-only table. [See here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html) for more info. As I understand using this type improves scalability (of updates).
3. If writing to timeline with every new like/comment/share becomes too expensive, an in-memory cache can be employed: counters are stored in cache and looked up when timeline is generated. Timeline stored values updates could then be delayed and serve as a fallback for counters which are not in cache. Looking up 20 times from RAM for a single request is ok I think.

#3 can be useful if you count entry views. Since you're not counting views, updating timeline on every like/comment/share would be alright I think.

Comment: Thanks. It is similar to my solution, and my doubt was about the update of counters for every like/comment/share. Also the in-memory cache is one of my ideas but caching in memory all posts' counters needs too much RAM for many users... Don't you think?

Comment: You don't need to store all posts' counters in cache. Normally, it's only a portion of timeline that changes frequently - usually the latest entries.  You can, for example, store only the counters for items younger than 2 days.

And numbers don't take up much space. Storing 10,000 24-byte tuples requires 240KB.

Comment: Ok , this is true. What's the best way of storing counters in cache  (Redis...)? If i store only the items younger that 2 days, in case of an user who is seeing in his timeline items older than 2 days, should I get counters from Cassandra, shouldn't it?

Comment: You need to choose the best way of storing by trying. The most basic way - map post_id to counters - will do I think.

Right, counters for items older than 2 days can come from the timeline from Cassandra.

Comment: I think this answer is a good idea, redis can help in this situations.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to store individual posts and then retrieve all of them using a single range query - this would allow you to easily update individual posts with counter data, but you'd still be able to retrieve all posts in the timeline using one query.  See [this article](http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/) for an example using temperature recordings at a weather station.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  post_id text,
  post_time timestamp,
  post text,
  timeline_id set<text>,
  comments_count counter,
  PRIMARY KEY (post_id,post_time)
);
```

---

```
CREATE INDEX timeline_id_index ON posts (timeline_id);
```

---

```
SELECT post, comments_count
FROM posts
WHERE timeline_id CONTAINS ’foo’
AND post_time > ’2013-04-03 07:01:00′
AND post_time < ’2020-04-03 07:04:00′;
```

---

```
UPDATE posts
SET comments_count = comments_count + 1
WHERE post_id='bar';
```

Comment: In the last statement, which is timeline's data model? Thanks

Comment: @user3443051 That was meant to be "posts" - I've updated my answer

Comment: I use push method and so every post is inserted in all followers' timelines. Using only one table posts is good for this?

Comment: @user3443051 My mistake, I thought it was one post per timeline.  See my updated answer - if you've got multiple timelines per post then you can use a `set<text>` (or `set<uuid>` or whatever) for `timeline_id`, then use `CONTAINS` on your query to retrieve all posts with a given timeline

Comment: Do you think set<uuid> is enough scalable to manage many concurrent insert (depending on followers' number)  and for select through CONTAINS?

Comment: @user3443051 Updates to the `set` are atomic, so it will scale with multiple writers; the `CONTAINS` will also be performant so long as you index the `set` column

Comment: Ok... If I want to add to this set many values sta the dame Time, have I to put insert in a for or is there another way of doing it? Is there a set limit in terms of elements which can be inserted?

Comment: @user3443051 You can add multiple items to a set, e.g. `timeline_id + {1, 2, 3}`; the limit to a `set` is that the maximum size of an element is 64kb, and you can't have more than 64k items in the set - the former shouldn't be a problem if you're just storing ids, whereas the latter might be a problem if you anticipate a lot of followers

Comment: 64kb items in the set are too small... So the only way to proceed is creating a timeline Table where the partition key is user_id (and the year to avoid reaching 2 billions row limit) but I have the initial problem of doing a query for posts and another (eventually in in-memory cache ad Redis) for posts' counters